# Testing equality of unconditional variance of two stationary AR times series?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, variance

Suppose I have two stationary AR time series:

$$
\begin{align}
y_{1,t} &= \phi_1 y_{1,t-1}+\varepsilon_{1,t} \\
y_{2,t} &= \phi_2 y_{2,t-1}+\varepsilon_{2,t}
\end{align}
$$

with $\varepsilon_{1,t} \stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \mathcal{WN}(0,\sigma_1^2)$ and $\varepsilon_{2,t} \stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \mathcal{WN}(0,\sigma_2^2)$

I know their unconditional variances

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(y_{1,t}) &= \frac{\sigma_1^2}{1-\phi_1^2} \\
\mathrm{Var}(y_{2,t}) &= \frac{\sigma_2^2}{1-\phi_1^2}
\end{align}
$$

**Q**: How do I formally test the hypothesis $H_0: \mathrm{Var}(y_{1,t})=\mathrm{Var}(y_{2,t})$?

I know that if all I were testing were, say, $H_0: \mathrm{Var}(y_{1,t})=5$, I could do some sort of classical LR, LM, or Wald test. But I'm trying to test equality of two populations.

I guess what I'm looking for is something like a two-sample t-test or F-test of equality of population means or variances. But those are for i.i.d. data. I have auto-correlation here.

I could bootstrap, sampling from the most likely model for each population, re-estimating models for each, calculating the bootstrap sample unconditional variance for each, looking at their difference or ratio, comparing what would arise from a null of equality.

But there must be an easier, straightforward way. I think I'm missing something fundamental here.